# mongoose: find most recent document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoose schema which has a day attribute which is just

```
Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / (24 * 3600 * 1000))
```

and I want to find the data for the last day entered so say today is `16085` then I want to find the last day entered. Or another way of saying this would be. What is the document with a `day` attribute less then `16085` but greater then all other documents where `day` is also less then `16085`.

or another way

What is the maximal element of the set of all documents with a `day` attribute less then `16085`

Other then iterating over all of my documents, how could I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the shell it would be:

```
db.test.find({day: {$lt: 16085}}).sort({day: -1}).limit(1)
```

Which finds all the docs where `day` is less than 16085, sorts them on `day` descending, and then takes the first one.

In Mongoose it would be something like:

```
MyModel.find({day: {$lt: 16085}}).sort({day: -1}).limit(1).exec((err, docs) => { ... });
```

Comment: awesome thanks. Is there someone to have the result of this passed to a callback?

Comment: @Loourr The shell doesn't use callbacks, but I added a Mongoose example that shows it.

Comment: how does the callback know what the returned value is?

Comment: @ingrid The query result documents are passed into the callback as the second parameter. See updated example.