# How can I get the most recent documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose a have a collection with the following documents:

```
{
    _id:        0,
    data:       'foo',
    createdAt:  Tue Sep 30 2014 17:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)
}

{
    _id:        1,
    data:       'foo',
    createdAt:  Tue Sep 30 2014 18:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)
}

{
    _id:        2,
    data:       'foo',
    createdAt:  Tue Sep 30 2014 18:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)
}

{
    _id:        3,
    data:       'bar',
    createdAt:  Tue Sep 30 2014 18:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)
}
```

How can I get all the most recent `{data: 'foo'}` documents in "one operation"? In this case, the documents with `_id` `1` and `2`.

I don't know how many elements are, so I can't do:

```
db.coll.find({data: 'foo', createdAt: ???})
```

or:

```
db.coll.find({data: 'foo'}).sort({createdAt: -1}).limit(???);
```

The only way I know has two steps:

```
var d = db.coll.find({data: 'foo'}).sort({createdAt: -1}).next();
var c = db.coll.find({data: 'foo', createdAt: d.createdAt});
```

There is a way to do this in one single step?

Related question: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128060/mongoose-find-most-recent-document).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all you care about is the ID and the time, and don't need to see the entire document of each of the returned document, you could use the [Aggregation Framework.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)

Here's an untested example that would return the most recent timestamp along with all of the _id values that go along with it.

```
db.coll.aggregate({$match: {data: 'foo'}}, {$group: {_id: '$created_at', id: {$addToSet: '$_id'}}}, {$sort: {_id: -1}}, {$limit: 1})
```

Comment: With a date format like this, I really doubt that this will work. Will do some research.

Comment: Sure it will. What don't you like about it? The group will work as long as the elements can be seen as equal. The Sort will depend on whether its stored as a timestamp or a string. I assume its a timestamp since there are no quotes and he already shows the ability to sort in his example.